# Find the function $f$ such that $g_{x}(z)=f(x,z)$, $g_{y}(z) =f(z,y)$

Tags: analysis

Find the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g_{x}(z)=f(x,z)$, $g_{y}(z)=f(z,y)$ are continuous, but $f$ is not continuous($\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Tried working with an example?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the map, $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ defined by, 
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if}\;(x,y)\not=(0,0) \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

You can verify that $f$ is not continuous and that it is continuous in each variable seperately.